# How to shuffle objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently having a problem on javascript. please help me on how can i shuffle this one within an array. i would really appreciate any help. Thank you so much!

```
    // ______________________________________________Function to declare our var -> deck of cards

function getDeck() {

    var deck = [
        {suit: "H", face: "A"},
        {suit: "H", face: "2"},
        {suit: "H", face: "3"},
        {suit: "H", face: "4"},
        {suit: "H", face: "5"},
        {suit: "H", face: "6"},
        {suit: "H", face: "7"},
        {suit: "H", face: "8"},
        {suit: "H", face: "9"},
        {suit: "H", face: "10"},
        {suit: "H", face: "J"},
        {suit: "H", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "H", face: "K"},
        {suit: "C", face: "A"},
        {suit: "C", face: "2"},
        {suit: "C", face: "3"},
        {suit: "C", face: "4"},
        {suit: "C", face: "5"},
        {suit: "C", face: "6"},
        {suit: "C", face: "7"},
        {suit: "C", face: "8"},
        {suit: "C", face: "9"},
        {suit: "C", face: "10"},
        {suit: "C", face: "J"},
        {suit: "C", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "C", face: "K"},
        {suit: "D", face: "A"},
        {suit: "D", face: "2"},
        {suit: "D", face: "3"},
        {suit: "D", face: "4"},
        {suit: "D", face: "5"},
        {suit: "D", face: "6"},
        {suit: "D", face: "7"},
        {suit: "D", face: "8"},
        {suit: "D", face: "9"},
        {suit: "D", face: "10"},
        {suit: "D", face: "J"},
        {suit: "D", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "D", face: "K"},
        {suit: "S", face: "A"},
        {suit: "S", face: "2"},
        {suit: "S", face: "3"},
        {suit: "S", face: "4"},
        {suit: "S", face: "5"},
        {suit: "S", face: "6"},
        {suit: "S", face: "7"},
        {suit: "S", face: "8"},
        {suit: "S", face: "9"},
        {suit: "S", face: "10"},
        {suit: "S", face: "J"},
        {suit: "S", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "S", face: "K"},
    ];

    return deck;
}
```

This is the shuffle codes. i don't know if this is correct so kindly please check also. Thank you!

```
// ______________________________________________Function to shuffle cards

function shuffle(o) { // o is passed-in array

     for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i, 10), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
     return o;

};


// ______________________________________________Function to retrieve our deck of cards & save into localStorage

function getShoe(decks) {

    var shoe = [];
    var deck = getDeck();
    this.decks = decks;

        for (z=1;z<=decks;z++) {
            shoe.push(deck);
        }

    shoe = shuffle(shoe);
    return shoe;


    localStorage.setItem('shoe', JSON.stringify(shoe));

}
```

Comment: What the hell is happening in that `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is:

```
var shoe = [];          // create an empty array
var deck = getDeck();   // create a SINGLE deck
this.decks = decks;

    for (z=1;z<=decks;z++) {
        shoe.push(deck);  // insert the SAME deck many times into the array
    }

shoe = shuffle(shoe); // you shuffle the array that contains the same deck many times, not the decks
return shoe;
```

You can do:

```
var shoe = [];
for (var i=0; i<decks; i++){
    shoe.push(shuffle(getDeck()));
}
return shoe;
```

Comment: not shuffling yet
var shoe = [];
 var deck = getDeck();

  for (var i=0; i<decks; i++) {
      shoe.push(shuffle(deck));
  }
 
 return shoe;
i tried yours too
var shoe = [];
for (var i=0; i<decks; i++){
    shoe.push(shuffle(getDeck()));
}
return shoe;
i think b/c after i try to shuffle
i save into local storage
and the output from local storage is still a non shuffled deck

Comment: i just tried it and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/GzwJa/ you can open the JS console and see that each deck inside the shoe is different